# Detect which MovieClip on the stage when they appear randomly

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3.

I've got a class "Dechets" where 3 movieClips appears randomly.

```
    public var _classes:Array = new Array(coco1, coco2, coco3,coco4);
    public var _cocoMovieClips:Array = new Array(); 

    public function cocoAppear(event : TimerEvent):void{
    var cocoMc:DisplayObject = new _classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * _classes.length)]();
    _cocoMovieClips.push(cocoMc);
    stageRef.addChild(cocoMc);
    cocoMc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, removeCoco, false, 0, true); 
                trace( getOnStage() );

}
        public function removeCoco(event:MouseEvent):void{
var cocoMc:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;
    if (!cocoMc) return; // typecast failed
    cocoMc.parent.removeChild(cocoMc);
            trace(cocoMc);
}
```

So, do you know how can I put

```
    if(cocoMc == "coco4"){
    doSomething();

}
```

?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the question ?

You want to know wich object is on the stage ? maybe try to remove the items from the array when you remove them from the stage or make a second array for this if you want to keep the first with all of the items.

ex:

```
public function removeCoco(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var cocoMc:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;

    if (!cocoMc) return;

    cocoMc.parent.removeChild(cocoMc);

    // get the index of the cocoMc in the array
    var i:int = _cocoMovieClips.indexOf( cocoMc );
    // remove the cocoMc from the array
    if( i != -1 )    _cocoMovieClips.splice( i, 1 );

    // if you want to check the type of your mc
    if( cocoMc is coco4 )         doSomething();
    else if( cocoMc is coco3 )    doSomethingElse();
}
```

after that you can just trace your array:

```
trace( _cocoMovieClips );
```

if you have lot of type to test you can replace :

```
// if you want to check the type of your mc
if( cocoMc is coco4 )         doSomething();
else if( cocoMc is coco3 )    doSomethingElse();
```

by:

```
var classe:String = getQualifiedClassName( cocoMc);
classe = classe.substring( classe.lastIndexOf(':')+1 );
switch( classe )
{
    case 'coco1': doSomething1(); break;
    case 'coco2': doSomething2(); break;
    case 'coco3': doSomething3(); break;
    case 'coco4': doSomething4(); break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know which in your array is on the stage:

```
function getOnStage():DisplayObject
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < _classes.length; i++)
    {
        if(_classes[i] is DisplayObject)
        {
            var o:DisplayObject = _classes[i] as DisplayObject;
            if(stage.contains(o)) return o;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Used like:

```
trace( getOnStage() );
```

Comment: also, check out these, because i feel you're going to need these in future of this case;
`flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName`
`flash.utils.getDefinitionByName`

Comment: Thank you. But I've got an error with the code you gave me. Error 1170 : Function does not return a value . Any idea why ?

Comment: The game starts with the updated function you gave me, but when the function is called I've got this error : Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert coco1$ to flash.display.MovieClip

Comment: Its because coco1 is in an Array.. but I need it that way in order to add it randomly with coco2, coco3..ect Is there a solution ?

Comment: @user2421975 Do you mean `coco1` is within `_classes`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47233/discussion-between-user2421975-and-marty)

Comment: Yes, it is. Is it annoying?

Comment: @user2421975 It would return null if 1) the array contains no display objects or 2) none of those objects are on the stage.

Comment: 1) I think the array contains the display object as they are appearing in the stage 2)There are 3 objects on stage when trace is called...

Comment: In the function public function removeCoco if I put trace(cocoMc); I've got "object coco1" when I click on it or 'object coco2" when I click on the other. So it may be possible to use cocoMc no ? (it's defined like that :     var cocoMc:DisplayObject = new _cocos[Math.floor(Math.random() * _cocos.length)]();

Comment: I've eddited the orignal post as I've made some mistakes with the names in it. Is it clearer ?